# Setting 2 equations equal in modular arithmetic

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Let us say that I have some m, say $5z+25$ (where $z$ is some random integer), and $n$ is say $3z+9$ (same $z$). I want to find an equation that correlates $m$ and $n$ in some $\text{mod} \,O$. Normally in algebra, I would have $m = \frac 53 n+10$. But, since we don't have fractions in modular arithmetic, what would this equation be?

In other words, is there an equation mod O that expresses m in terms of n, or n in terms of m for all values of z?

Comment: I don't quite understand what it is you're trying to do/solve.

Comment: Well, I just ran into this problem and have no idea how to do this in mods. It doesn't have to be these numbers, I chose 5 and 3 off the top of my head

Comment: So you're trying to simultaneaously solve $5z + 25\ (\operatorname{mod} O)$ and $3z+9\ (\operatorname{mod} O)$ for $z$ (so that you can plug it into your expressions for $n$ and $m$)?

Comment: No, I want to eliminate the z and find m in terms of n (or n in terms of m)

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand modular arithmetic. Z would equal (m-25)/5 = m/5-5, and n/3-3 but we can't have fractions...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to solve
$$5z+25\equiv3z+9\pmod O\ .$$
This can be written as
$$2z\equiv-16\pmod O\ .$$
If $O$ is odd you can cancel $2$ to give
$$z\equiv-8\pmod O\ ,$$
if $O$ is even, say $O=2P$, then
$$z\equiv-8\pmod P\ .$$
If you are just looking for one solution, then $z=-8$ will do in any case.

If you want to know how to do this sort of thing with different numbers, Google "solving linear congruences" - there are heaps of resources available online.